# Reverse Singly Linked List Java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Can someone tell me why my code dosent work? I want to reverse a single linked list in java: This is the method (that doesnt work correctly)

```
public void reverseList(){
    Node before = null;
    Node tmp = head;
    Node next = tmp.next;
    while(tmp != null){
      if(next == null)
         return;
      tmp.next = before;
      before = tmp;
      tmp = next;
      next = next.next;
    }
}
```

And this is the Node class:

```
public class Node{
   public int data;
   public Node next;
   public Node(int data, Node next){
      this.data = data;
      this.next = next;
   }
}
```

On input 4->3->2->1 I got output 4. I debugged it and it sets pointers correctly but still I dont get why it outputs only 4.

Comment: Complete step wise explanation with animation. Best solution on single iteration.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txqLgAdgyVM&t=83s

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
Node next = tmp.next;
while(tmp != null){
```

So what happens when tmp == null?

You almost got it, though.

```
Node before = null;
Node tmp = head;
while (tmp != null) {
    Node next = tmp.next;
    tmp.next = before;
    before = tmp;
    tmp = next;
}
head = before;
```

Or in nicer (?) naming:

```
Node reversedPart = null;
Node current = head;
while (current != null) {
    Node next = current.next;
    current.next = reversedPart;
    reversedPart = current;
    current = next;
}
head = reversedPart;
```

ASCII art:

```
        <__<__<__ __ : reversedPart    : head
                 (__)__ __ __
head :   current:      >  >  >
```

Comment: Hey can't we put the "Node next = current.next" line outside the while loop? and just put "next = current.next" inside the while loop? and just like for reversedPart and current, we just put "Node next = null" outside the while loop?

Comment: @Satnamxv63 thanks for the idea, but in java there is no penalty for a declaration inside a loop as opposed to outside. There is only once one variable slot reserved for `next`.

Comment: @dharam nice; can only be topped by an animated gif or such.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks. About animated gifs, will take care next time.

Comment: Great Solution!! Thanks

Comment: Complete step wise explanation with animation. Best solution on single iteration.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txqLgAdgyVM&t=83s

Answer (score 21):

```
public Node<E> reverseList(Node<E> node) {
    if (node == null || node.next == null) {
        return node;
    }
    Node<E> currentNode = node;
    Node<E> previousNode = null;
    Node<E> nextNode = null;

    while (currentNode != null) {
        nextNode = currentNode.next;
        currentNode.next = previousNode;
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }
    return previousNode;
}
```

Comment: Complete step wise explanation with animation. Best solution on single iteration.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txqLgAdgyVM&t=83s

Answer (score 13):

The method for reversing a linked list is as below;

### Reverse Method

```
public void reverseList() {
    Node<E> curr = head;
    Node<E> pre = null;
    Node<E> incoming = null;

    while(curr != null) {
        incoming = curr.next;   // store incoming item

        curr.next = pre;        // swap nodes
        pre = curr;             // increment also pre

        curr = incoming;        // increment current
    }

    head = pre; // pre is the latest item where
                // curr is null
}
```

Three references are needed to reverse a list: **pre**, **curr**, **incoming**

```
...      pre     curr    incoming
... --> (n-1) --> (n) --> (n+1) --> ...
```

To reverse a node, you have to store **pre**vious element, so that you can use the simple stament;

```
curr.next = pre;
```

To reverse the current element's direction. However, to iterate over the list, you have to store incoming element before the execution of the statement above because as reversing the current element's next reference, you don't know the incoming element anymore, that's why a third reference needed.

The demo code is as below;

### LinkedList Sample Class

```
public class LinkedList<E> {

    protected Node<E> head;

    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;
    }

    public LinkedList(E[] list) {
        this();
        addAll(list);
    }

    public void addAll(E[] list) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            add(list[i]);
    }

    public void add(E e) {
        if(head == null)
            head = new Node<E>(e);
        else {
            Node<E> temp = head;

            while(temp.next != null)
                temp = temp.next;

            temp.next = new Node<E>(e);
        }
    }

    public void reverseList() {
        Node<E> curr = head;
        Node<E> pre = null;
        Node<E> incoming = null;

        while(curr != null) {
            incoming = curr.next;   // store incoming item

            curr.next = pre;        // swap nodes
            pre = curr;             // increment also pre

            curr = incoming;        // increment current
        }

        head = pre; // pre is the latest item where
                    // curr is null
    }

    public void printList() {
        Node<E> temp = head;

        System.out.print("List: ");
        while(temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public static class Node<E> {

        protected E e;
        protected Node<E> next;

        public Node(E e) {
            this.e = e;
            this.next = null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return e.toString();
        }

    }

}
```

### Test Code

```
public class ReverseLinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] list = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };

        LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>(list);

        linkedList.printList();
        linkedList.reverseList();
        linkedList.printList();
    }

}
```

### Output

```
List: 4 3 2 1 
List: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: A very nice and clear answer! Deserve more votes.

Comment: Complete step wise explanation with animation. Best solution on single iteration.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txqLgAdgyVM&t=83s

Answer (score 9):

If this isn't homework and you are doing this "manually" on purpose, then I would recommend using

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Collections.reverse() returns void, and your list is reversed after the call.

Comment: May I know why -1? Collections.reverse() reverses a list, and this was the question, wasn't it?

Comment: The Node class provided in the question is not a List type, thus can't be an argument for Collections.reverse(List<T> list) method. Note that this is a singly linked list and doesn't use any of Java's implementation of Linked List. Your answer would be true if the problem tried to reverse for example a LinkedList object.

Answer (score 4):

We can have three nodes previous,current and next.

```
public void reverseLinkedlist()
{
    /*
     * Have three nodes i.e previousNode,currentNode and nextNode
 When currentNode is starting node, then previousNode will be null
 Assign currentNode.next to previousNode to reverse the link.
 In each iteration move currentNode and previousNode by  1 node.
     */

    Node previousNode = null;
    Node currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode != null) 
    {
        Node nextNode = currentNode.next;
        currentNode.next = previousNode;
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }
    head = previousNode;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void reverse() {
    Node prev = null; Node current = head; Node next = current.next;
    while(current.next != null) {
        current.next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
        next = current.next;
    }
    current.next = prev;
    head = current;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    // Java program for reversing the linked list
    class LinkedList {

        static Node head;

        static class Node {

            int data;
            Node next;

            Node(int d) {
                data = d;
                next = null;
            }
        }

      //  Function to reverse the linked list 
        Node reverse(Node node) {
            Node prev = null;
            Node current = node;
            Node next = null;
            while (current != null) {
                next = current.next;
                current.next = prev;
                prev = current;
                current = next;
            }
            node = prev;
            return node;
        }




        // prints content of double linked list
        void printList(Node node) {
            while (node != null) {
                System.out.print(node.data + " ");
                node = node.next;
            }
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
            list.head = new Node(85);
            list.head.next = new Node(15);
            list.head.next.next = new Node(4);
            list.head.next.next.next = new Node(20);

            System.out.println("Given Linked list");
            list.printList(head);
            head = list.reverse(head);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Reversed linked list ");
            list.printList(head);
        }
    }


OUTPUT: -

Given Linked list
85 15 4 20 
Reversed linked list 
20 4 15 85
```

Comment: Please explain what your answer is doing and how it's doing it

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below code and it works fine:

```
Node head = firstNode;
Node current = head;
while(current != null && current.next != null){
    Node temp = current.next;
    current.next = temp.next;
    temp.next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

Basically one by one it sets the next pointer of one node to its next to next node, so from next onwards all nodes are attached at the back of the list.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 1):

I know the recursive solution is not the optimal one, but just wanted to add one here:

```
public class LinkedListDemo {

    static class Node {
        int val;
        Node next;

        public Node(int val, Node next) {
            this.val = val;
            this.next = next;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "" + val;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node n = new Node(1, new Node(2, new Node(3, new Node(20, null))));
        display(n);
        n = reverse(n);
        display(n);
    }

    static Node reverse(Node n) {
        Node tail = n;
        while (tail.next != null) {
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        reverseHelper(n);
        return (tail);
    }

    static Node reverseHelper(Node n) {
        if (n.next != null) {
            Node reverse = reverseHelper(n.next);
            reverse.next = n;
            n.next = null;
            return (n);
        }
        return (n);
    }

    static void display(Node n) {
        for (; n != null; n = n.next) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it... why not doing this :

```
private LinkedList reverseLinkedList(LinkedList originalList){
    LinkedList reversedList = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i=0 ; i<originalList.size() ; i++){
        reversedList.add(0, originalList.get(i));
    }

    return reversedList;
}
```

I find this easier.

Comment: Because the question is about a singly linked list and your solution uses Java's LinkedList, which has many functions that a basic singly list doesn't have. For example, your code would not be possible if there was no get(index) method provided by Java. In this case the Node class doesn't have such method.

Comment: It is easier and you wasted twice much memory thus the code you've provided is not memory-efficient. Also you don't even know when garbage collector is going to free the unused old list.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution would be to use recursion

```
void ReverseList(ListNode current, ListNode previous) {
            if(current.Next != null) 
            {
                ReverseList(current.Next, current);
                ListNode temp = current.Next;
                temp.Next = current;
                current.Next = previous;
            }
        }
```

Comment: In a very large list, this code would get a stack overflow. It is a bad choice to use recursion rather than using an iterative solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Node reverse_rec(Node start) {
    if (start == null || start -> next == null) {
       return start;
    }

    Node new_start = reverse(start->next);
    start->next->next = start;
    start->next = null;
    return new_start;
}


Node reverse(Node start) {
    Node cur = start;
    Node bef = null;

    while (cur != null) {
       Node nex = cur.next;
       cur.next = bef;
       bef = cur;
       cur = nex;
    }
    return bef;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
if (current== null || current.next==null) return current;
 Node nextItem = current.next;
 current.next = null;
 Node reverseRest = reverse(nextItem);
 nextItem.next = current;
 return reverseRest
```

or [Java Program to reverse a Singly Linked List](http://www.technicalypto.com/2010/01/java-program-to-reverse-singly-linked.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your initially last element *next* attribute isn't being changed becuase of your condition

```
if(next == null)
     return;
```

Is at the beginning of your loop.

I would move it right after tmp.next has been assigned:

```
while(tmp != null){

  tmp.next = before;
  if(next == null)
     return;
  before = tmp;
  tmp = next;
  next = next.next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.three;

public class Link {

    int a;
    Link Next;

    public Link(int i){
        a=i;
    }

}

public class LinkList {

    Link First = null;

    public void insertFirst(int a){
        Link objLink = new Link(a);

        objLink.Next=First;
        First = objLink;

    }

    public void displayLink(){

        Link current = First;
        while(current!=null){
            System.out.println(current.a);
            current = current.Next;
        }

    }

    public void ReverseLink(){
        Link current = First;
        Link Previous = null;
        Link temp = null;

        while(current!=null){

            if(current==First)
                temp = current.Next;
            else
                temp=current.Next;

            if(temp==null){
                First = current;
                //return;
            }
            current.Next=Previous;
            Previous=current;
            //System.out.println(Previous);
            current = temp;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        LinkList objLinkList = new LinkList();
        objLinkList.insertFirst(1);
        objLinkList.insertFirst(2);
        objLinkList.insertFirst(3);
        objLinkList.insertFirst(4);
        objLinkList.insertFirst(5);
        objLinkList.insertFirst(6);
        objLinkList.insertFirst(7);
        objLinkList.insertFirst(8);
        objLinkList.displayLink();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        objLinkList.ReverseLink();
        objLinkList.displayLink();

    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer appears to be all code. The best answers explain what is happening in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
    LinkedListNode pointer = head;
    LinkedListNode prev = null, curr = null;

    /* Pointer variable loops through the LL */
    while(pointer != null)
    {
        /* Proceed the pointer variable. Before that, store the current pointer. */
        curr = pointer; //          
        pointer = pointer.next;         

        /* Reverse the link */
        curr.next = prev;

        /* Current becomes previous for the next iteration */
        prev = curr;            
    }

    System.out.println(prev.printForward());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SinglyLinkedListImpl<T> {

    private Node<T> head;

    public void add(T element) {
        Node<T> item = new Node<T>(element);
        if (head == null) {
            head = item;
        } else {
            Node<T> temp = head;
            while (temp.next != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = item;
        }
    }

    private void reverse() {

        Node<T> temp = null;
        Node<T> next = null;
        while (head != null) {
            next = head.next;
            head.next = temp;
            temp = head;
            head = next;
        }
        head = temp;
    }

    void printList(Node<T> node) {
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            node = node.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        SinglyLinkedListImpl<Integer> sl = new SinglyLinkedListImpl<Integer>();
        sl.add(1);
        sl.add(2);
        sl.add(3);
        sl.add(4);

        sl.printList(sl.head);
        sl.reverse();
        sl.printList(sl.head);

    }

    static class Node<T> {

        private T data;
        private Node<T> next;

        public Node(T data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package LinkedList;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkedListNode {

    private int value;
    private LinkedListNode next = null;

    public LinkedListNode(int i) {
        this.value = i;
    }

    public LinkedListNode addNode(int i) {
        this.next = new LinkedListNode(i);
        return next;
    }

    public LinkedListNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String restElement = value+"->";
        LinkedListNode newNext = getNext();
        while(newNext != null)
            {restElement = restElement + newNext.value + "->";
            newNext = newNext.getNext();}
        restElement = restElement +newNext;
        return restElement;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListNode headnode = new LinkedListNode(1);
        headnode.addNode(2).addNode(3).addNode(4).addNode(5).addNode(6);

        System.out.println(headnode);
        headnode = reverse(null,headnode,headnode.getNext());

        System.out.println(headnode);
    }

    private static LinkedListNode reverse(LinkedListNode prev, LinkedListNode current, LinkedListNode next) {
        current.setNext(prev);
        if(next == null)
            return current;
         return reverse(current,next,next.getNext());   
    }

    private void setNext(LinkedListNode prev) {
        this.next = prev;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReverseLinkedList {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
        linkedList.add("a");
        linkedList.add("b");
        linkedList.add("c");
        linkedList.add("d");
        linkedList.add("e");
        linkedList.add("f");
        System.out.println("Original linkedList:");
        for(int i = 0; i <=linkedList.size()-1; i++){

            System.out.println(" - "+ linkedList.get(i));

        }
        LinkedList<String> reversedlinkedList = reverse(linkedList);
        System.out.println("Reversed linkedList:");
        for(int i = 0; i <=reversedlinkedList.size()-1; i++){
            System.out.println(" - "+ reversedlinkedList.get(i));

        }
    }

    public static LinkedList<String> reverse(LinkedList<String> linkedList){

        for(int i = 0; i < linkedList.size()/2; i++){
            String temp = linkedList.get(i);
            linkedList.set(i, linkedList.get(linkedList.size()-1-i));
            linkedList.set((linkedList.size()-1-i), temp);
        }
        return linkedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: accessing a linked list via get() and set() is ineffective; with every access you hae to iterate from the beginning or end

Answer (score 0):

To reverse a singly linked list you should have three nodes, **top**, **beforeTop** and **AfterTop**. Top is the header of singly linked list, hence **beforeTop** would be null and **afterTop** would be next element of **top** and with each iteration move forward  **beforeTop** is assigned **top** and **top** is assigned **afterTop**(i.e. **top**.**next**).

```
private static Node inverse(Node top) {
        Node beforeTop=null, afterTop;
        while(top!=null){
            afterTop=top.next;
            top.next=beforeTop;
            beforeTop=top;
            top=afterTop;
        }
        return beforeTop;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Recursion It's too easy :

```
package com.config;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Help {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Node head = null;
        Node temp = null;
        int choice = 0;
        boolean flage = true;
        do{
            Node node = new Node();
            System.out.println("Enter Node");
            node.data = sc.nextInt();
            if(flage){
                head = node;
                flage = false;
            }
            if(temp!=null)
                temp.next = node;
            temp = node;

            System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit.");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
        }while(choice!=0);

        Help.getAll(head);

        Node reverse = Help.reverse(head,null);
        //reverse = Help.reverse(head, null);

        Help.getAll(reverse);

    }

    public static void getAll(Node head){
        if(head==null)
            return ;
        System.out.println(head.data+"Memory Add "+head.hashCode());
        getAll(head.next);
    }

    public static Node reverse(Node head,Node tail){
        Node next = head.next;
        head.next = tail;
        return (next!=null? reverse(next,head) : head);
    }
}

class Node{
    int data = 0;
    Node next = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Node Reverse(Node head) {
        Node n,rev;
        rev = new Node();
        rev.data = head.data;
        rev.next = null;


        while(head.next != null){
            n = new Node();
            head = head.next;
            n.data = head.data;
            n.next = rev;
            rev = n;
            n=null;


        }
    return rev;
}
```

Use above function to reverse single linked list.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
    ListNode prev = null;
    ListNode curr = head;
    while (curr != null) {
        ListNode nextTemp = curr.next;
        curr.next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = nextTemp;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

check more details about complexity analysis
http://javamicro.com/ref-card/DS-Algo/How-to-Reverse-Singly-Linked-List?

Comment: It would be good if you comment your approach better to include only a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static LinkedList reverseLinkedList(LinkedList node) {
    if (node == null || node.getNext() == null) {
        return node;
    }

    LinkedList remaining = reverseLinkedList(node.getNext());
    node.getNext().setNext(node);
    node.setNext(null);
    return remaining;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Reverse LinkedList
 * @author asharda
 *
 */

class Node
{
  int data;
  Node next;
  Node(int data)
  {
    this.data=data;
  }
}
public class ReverseLinkedList {

  static Node root;
  Node temp=null;
  public void insert(int data)
  {
    if(root==null)
    {
      root=new Node(data);

    }
    else
    {
      temp=root;
      while(temp.next!=null)
      {
        temp=temp.next;
      }

      Node newNode=new Node(data);
      temp.next=newNode;
    }
  }//end of insert

  public void display(Node head)
  {
    while(head!=null)
    {
      System.out.println(head.data);
      head=head.next;
    }

  }

  public Node reverseLinkedList(Node head)
  {
    Node newNode;
    Node tempr=null;
    while(head!=null)
    {
      newNode=new Node(head.data);
      newNode.next=tempr;
      tempr=newNode;
      head=head.next;
    }
    return tempr;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReverseLinkedList r=new ReverseLinkedList();
    r.insert(10);
    r.insert(20);
    r.insert(30);
    r.display(root);
    Node t=r.reverseLinkedList(root);
    r.display(t);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Linkedtest {
    public static void reverse(List<Object> list) {

        int lenght = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght / 2; i++) {
            Object as = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, list.get(lenght - 1 - i));
            list.set(lenght - 1 - i, as);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Object> st = new LinkedList<Object>();
        st.add(1);
        st.add(2);
        st.add(3);
        st.add(4);
        st.add(5);
        Linkedtest.reverse(st);
        System.out.println("Reverse Value will be:"+st);
    }
}
```

This will be useful for any type of collection Object.

Comment: Check its Tested code