# Reversing and printing a singly linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have written this program that reverses a singly linked list and prints it. The problem is that I can't print the reverse order and it gives me StackOverFlowError. The problem may be with my Reverse method. Any help will be appreciated.

```
private static Node head;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    GettingNumbers();
}

public static void Reverse(Node node)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        Reverse(node.next);
        System.out.print(" " + node.key);
    }
}
public static void GettingNumbers()
{   
    head = new Node();
    head = null;
    Node last = new Node();
    String str = new String();

    System.out.print("Enter a number or # to stop: ");
    str = console.next();

    while (!(str.trim().equals("#")))
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.key = str;
        node.next= null;

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = node;
            last = node;
        }
        else
        {
            last.next = node;
            last = node;
        }

        System.out.print("Enter a number or # to stop: ");
        str = console.next();
    }
    Node h = head;
    if (head == null || head.next == null)
    {
        return;  //empty or just one node in list
    }

    Node Second = head.next;

    //store third node before we change 
    Node Third = Second.next;  

    //Second's next pointer
    Second.next = head;  //second now points to head
    head.next = null;  //change head pointer to NULL

    //only two nodes, which we already reversed
    if (Third == null)
    {
        return;  
    }

    Node CurrentNode = Third;

    Node PreviousNode = Second;

    while (CurrentNode != null)
    { 
        Node NextNode = CurrentNode.next;

        CurrentNode.next = PreviousNode;

        /*  repeat the process, but have to reset
             the PreviousNode and CurrentNode
        */

        PreviousNode = CurrentNode;
        CurrentNode = NextNode;  

    }

    head  = PreviousNode; //reset the head node
    Reverse(h);

    return;

}
}
```

Comment: The problem with recursion for tranversing a list is that you end up with a method call on the memory stack for each element in the list. Once the list is beyond a trivial size, you run the risk of using all your memory and getting a `StackOverflowError`

Comment: You should remove all the `SecondNode`, `ThirdNode` stuff to try to localize the issue. You have so much odd stuff going on there it is hard to determine if you have created an look in your list.

Comment: what these two lines says `head = new Node(); head = null;`

Comment: Comment update...  it is hard to determine if you have created a loop in your list. This is usually the cause of this error: a loop or a recursion that is too deep.

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below:

```
 Node previousNode=null;
      Node nextNode;
      while(currentNode!=null)
      {
       nextNode=currentNode.next;
      // reversing the link
       currentNode.next=previousNode;
      // moving currentNode and previousNode by 1 node
       previousNode=currentNode;
       currentNode=nextNode;
      }
```

Have a look at this answer with detailed explanation: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44068199/3148734