# Reverse single linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I was implementing the "reverse single linked list, do it in-place" task. I came up with this solution:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        if (head == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if(head.next==null) return head;

        ListNode n = head;
        ListNode r = null;
        ListNode temp = null;

        while (n != null) {
            temp = n;
            n = n.next;
            temp.next = r;
            r = temp;
        }

        return r;
    }
}
```

and it works:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1
```

but when I wanted to make sure it's the right approach all the solutions I've seen online look like that [Reverse single linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605050/reverse-singly-linked-list-java) so I started questioning myself... What is wrong with my solution? Time complexity looks like O(n) space com. O(1)... Am I wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your solutions looks good to me!. I did a check against leetcode(https://leetcode.com/) and it passed all test cases just fine. Just because there are other more popular solution means your own solution is wrong.

Comment: complexity must be at least the order of n, since you need to switch pointer direction for every node in the list

Comment: I know that time compl must be O(n), but what about space? Does my solution fits the requirement of space compl O(1)?

Comment: @grape yes, your space complexity is constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking. Your implementation looks almost just like the one in the link. Both implementations are `O(n)` for time complexity, and `O(1)` for space complexity. Of course, the list itself is `O(n)` for space complexity.

Comment: Compare the solustions closely, I'm doing it in different order, and the order her might be tricky

Comment: Actually I read yours first, and it made sense. Except that the variable names are... badly named XD

I didn't read the link's one in detail, though.

Comment: Nevertheless, all you wanted to know is time/space complexity right? I realized I was confused by the phrasing of your last sentence of the question.