# java Linked List Reverse

Tags: java

I am writing a LinkedList reverse method, in the main method, I am defining temp and calling reverse method (root contains the linked list)

```
Node temp=null;
r=a.reverse(root,temp);

public Node reverse(Node node,Node temp){
    if(node!=null){
        Node n=new Node();
        n.data=node.data;
        n.next=temp;
        temp=n;
        node=node.next;
        reverse(node,temp);
    }
    return temp;    
}
```

My rote contains 10,20,30,40,50`
while I print Node returned by reverse method, I get the output..
    o/p--- 10

Comment: I'm downvoting this, because it "does not show any research effort".  Simply [searching for your title](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+linked+list+reverse) turned up several already-answered questions on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dismissed the return of the call inside the function itself, and that's why the whole call is returning only the *temp* from the first call. This should work:

```
Node temp=null;
r=a.reverse(root,temp);

public Node reverse(Node node,Node temp) {
    if (node!=null){
        Node n=new Node();
        n.data=node.data;
        n.next=temp;
        temp=n;
        node=node.next;
        return reverse(node,temp); // Here now we return this result
    }
return temp;    
}
```

Also, I recommend you [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605050/reverse-singly-linked-list-java) with some other reversing methods.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Gustavo Sánchez